# JFileChooser not saving file even after entering the name

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

Below I've got a method containing a `JFileChooser`. The method is called when a button on my `JInternalFrame` is engaged. The idea is basically to export data from a `JTable` to an `.csv` file. This part works fine, but I want to then give the user the opportunity to save in a directory of their choice. I seem not to understand why the code below isn't doing the following things:

- Saving the file after selecting my desired filepath and
- When I enter the file name in the dialog box it doesn't save the file either.

Any help is appreciated.

Here's my `JFileChooser` code:

```
//!< Write data into excel sheet and export to desktop
public void writeBGEAuthnDataToXLS(JTable jTable1, BGEDSATableModel model) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String userHomeFolder = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String desktopFilePath = "C:\\Users\\" + userHomeFolder.substring(9, userHomeFolder.length()) + "\\Documents\\";

    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(desktopFilePath);

    fileChooser.setFileFilter(new TxtFilter());
    fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Select where to save");

    int saveDialogResult = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);

    if (saveDialogResult == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("BGE DSA USAGE ADMIN LOG IN DATA");

        Row r = null;
        Cell c = null;

        FileOutputStream fos;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fileChooser.getSelectedFile() + "\\BGE DSA USAGE ADMIN LOG IN DATA.csv");

        int rowNum;
        int colNum;
        int tempRows;
        int rowCount = model.getRowCount();
        int columnCount = model.getColumnCount();     

        for (colNum = 0; colNum < columnCount; colNum++) {

            if (colNum == 0) {
                r = sheet.createRow(0);
            }

            c = r.createCell(colNum);

            c.setCellValue(model.getColumnName(colNum));
        }

        for (rowNum = 0; rowNum < rowCount; rowNum++) {
            tempRows = rowNum + 1;

            r = sheet.createRow(tempRows);      

            for (short cellnum = 0; cellnum < columnCount; cellnum ++) {
                c = r.createCell(cellnum);
                try {
                    c.setCellValue(model.getValueAt(rowNum, cellnum).toString());
                } catch (NullPointerException x) {
                    System.out.println(x.toString());
                }
            }
        }

        wb.write(fos);

        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Here's my `JFileChooser` filter code:

```
public class TxtFilter extends FileFilter{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File f){
        return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".csv")||f.isDirectory();
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription(){
        return "CSV files (*.csv)";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JFileChooser does not save the file, you have to save it yourself. The only thing that you can get from JFileChooser is the selected file or directory.

```
    //File item/folder selected by the chooser.
    File inFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    //If the selection was a folder, you can then use that as the parent and create you file.
    File outFile = new File(inFile.getParent() + File.separator + "FILENAME.ext");
```

Then retrieve your data from your JTAble and write it to the file. There are CSV APIs out there, but the below link should do the trick.

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=42